# Line Smooth Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

[image]

See the image groups A and B.
You can easily find the difference.
Group A has a smoother RED line whereas Group B has RED line but it is not smoother.

My problem is, I want to make red line smoother in Group B.
Which algorithm will help me?
Or suggest me best algorithm for make that line smoother

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this line anti aliasing algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=66790FF999893EA91BB0CFFE9106EA06?doi=10.1.1.107.8760&rep=rep1&type=pdf). It's easy to implement.

Edit: Found [this](http://mlab.uiah.fi/~kkallio/antialiasing/) page (includes an flash presentation describing the algorithm)

Comment: Could you link to the page containing the PDF download link, rather than directly to the PDF?

Comment: @Steve,I'm sorry, but i don't have it, i just remembered the name of the algorithm and googled it....

Comment: @Steve, found that page...also a very cool flash presentation supporting it... :)

Comment: Very cool. May be worth adding that a line in a non-filled drawing can be seen as a long thin filled rectangle.